# EcmaScript Object.observer is not notifying property changes

Tags: ecmascript-6, observer-pattern, es6-proxy

I an using ES6 classes plus [Object.observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe), using the [MaxArt2501 implementation](https://github.com/MaxArt2501/object-observe). I have this code below:

```
const READY = Symbol("Ready");
const RUNNING = Symbol("Running");

class Foo {

    constructor() {
        this.value = 1;
        this.status = READY;
    }

    bar() {
        this.status = RUNNING;  
        console.log("bar", this.status );
        this.value = this.value + 10;
        this.status = READY;
        console.log("bar", this.status );
    }

}

let foo = new Foo();

Object.observe(foo, function(changes) {
    changes.forEach(function(change) {
        console.log("foo: ", change);
    });
});
```

My expectation was that when I execute the `bar()` method, the observer function would be called 3 times: When changing `foo.status` from `READY` to `RUNNING`, when changing `foo.value` and when changing `foo.status` from `RUNNING` to `READY`.

However, this is what I got when running `bar()` (In Chrome console):

```
> foo
Foo {value: 1, status: Symbol(Ready)}
> foo.bar()
bar Symbol(Running)
bar Symbol(Ready)
undefined
foo:  Object {name: "value", type: "update", object: Foo, oldValue: 1}
> foo
Foo {value: 11, status: Symbol(Ready)}
```

The undefined is the return from `bar()` method. But any way, it looks like just the changing in `foo.value` is really observed, but not `foo.status`.
If I change `foo.status` value "manually" it is observed:

```
> foo.status = RUNNING
Symbol(Running)
foo:  Object {name: "status", type: "update", object: Foo, oldValue: Symbol(Ready)}
> foo
Foo {value: 11, status: Symbol(Running)}
> foo.status = READY
Symbol(Ready)
foo:  Object {name: "status", type: "update", object: Foo, oldValue: Symbol(Running)}
> foo
Foo {value: 11, status: Symbol(Ready)}
```

I could say that when a property class is changed inside the class it does not notify its observer. However, the `foo.value` change in `bar()` method was observed.

Does someone have any idea about what is happening here?

Thanks,

Rafael Afonso

**UPDATE - 06/06**

I did a workaround which, although not exactly very elegant, I could use as base in my real implementation:

```
const READY = Symbol("Ready");
const RUNNING = Symbol("Running");

class Foo {

    constructor() {
        this.value = 1;
        this.status = READY;
    }

    bar() {
//      this.status = RUNNING;  
        console.log("bar", this.status );
        this.value = this.value + 10;
//      this.status = READY;
        console.log("bar", this.status );
    }

}

let foo = new Foo();

Object.observe(foo, function(changes) {
    changes.forEach(function(change) {
        if(change.name === 'value') {
            change.object.status = RUNNING;
        }
        console.log("foo: ", change);
    });
});
```

When I run, I got this:

```
> foo.bar()
bar Symbol(Ready)
bar Symbol(Ready)
undefined
foo:  Object {name: "value", type: "update", object: Foo, oldValue: 1}
foo:  Object {name: "status", type: "update", object: Foo, oldValue: Symbol(Ready)}
```

As you see, I change the `foo.status` in observable method. However, apparently just after the foo execution, both properties changes are notified.

I was thinking if would not be better use a approach such as [Observable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) and [Observer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) in Java. Does somebody know some JS library which implements in this way?

**UPDATE - 06/06 (2)**

As suggested, I tried use proxies:

```
const READY = Symbol("Ready");
const RUNNING = Symbol("Running");

class Foo {

    constructor() {
        this.value = 1;
        this.status = READY;
    }

    bar() {
        this.status = RUNNING;  
        // console.log("bar", this.status );
        this.value = this.value + 10;
        this.status = READY;
        // console.log("bar", this.status );
    }

}

let observer = {
    set: function(obj, prop, value) {
        let oldValue = obj[prop];
        let result = Reflect.set(obj, prop, value);
        console.log(prop + ": " + oldValue.toString() + " -> " + value.toString());
        return result;
    }
}

let foo = new Proxy(new Foo(), observer);
```

When I runned, I got this:

```
> foo.bar()
status: Symbol(Ready) -> Symbol(Running)
value: 1 -> 11
status: Symbol(Running) -> Symbol(Ready)
undefined
> foo.bar()
status: Symbol(Ready) -> Symbol(Running)
value: 11 -> 21
status: Symbol(Running) -> Symbol(Ready)
undefined
```

Indeed, this is what I was looking for. Although the Object.observer goals to intercept all kind of changes in the target, I am interested just in the properties setting.

Comment: FYI `Object.observe` was removed from the ES6 specification. It's obsolete.

Comment: I know, but I included this polyfill to meet my needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick skim of that repo [suggests](https://github.com/MaxArt2501/object-observe/blob/master/dist/object-observe.js#L232) that updates are only performed once per frame (in environments with such a notion) or once every 17ms.

Because JavaScript is single-threaded, if you change a property and and then change it back within a single uninterrupted function (i.e. not a generator etc), it will not be observable by this package.

Keep in mind that Object.observe is no longer on track to become part of the language. An actual implementation of the proposed spec could have given you notifications for each event, but it's not possible to fake for this specific situation (at least without wrapping every object in a proxy).